# Excel - New total for every inserted amount

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm trying to calculate a new total on the next cell in one column for every new addition to another column.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I want the Debit column to be subtracted from the Balance column, but one row at a time. For example, the formula for cell C3 would be `Sum(C2-A3)`, where Debit is the A column and Balance is the C column.I want that formula to iterate over the balance column, but I'm not sure how to do it. Anyone have any idea what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that formula -

```
=C2-A3+B3
```

and grab the lower right corner and drag it down. It will adjust as it drags. It will increase the cells you specify by 1 (C3,A4,B4). This is called [autofill](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db).

[image]

Also, if you want to do something similar but not have it adjust the reference, you can use `$` like `=$A$2-B3` would *always* reference A2, but change B3.

[image]